# Задача про площадь прямоугольного треугольника

Tags: c++

Задача про площадь прямоугольного треугольника.
Задано катеты. На сколько увеличится площадь прямоугольного треугольника, если один из катетов увеличить в 2 раза, а второй - в 3 раза?
Нужно решить эту задачу на языке C++.
Формула прямоугольного треугольника `1/2ab` (`1/2` это дробь).
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить!

Comment: А причём тут C++? Элементарная задача, даже не по геометрии, а чистая арифметика.

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно?

Comment: В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Cathetus a = ";
    double  a = 0;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Cathetus b = ";
    double  b = 0;
    cin >> b;

    double S1 = a * b / 2.0;
    cout << "Area S1 = " << S1 << endl; 

    double S2 = (a * 2) * (b * 3) / 2.0;
    cout << "If a2 = 2 * a and b2 = b * 3 then S2 = " << S2 << endl;
    cout << "Difference is S2 - S1 = " << S2 - S1 << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: вам нужно сравнить выражение x * 2 * 3 с выражением x.  Остается просто дать ответ: "в шесть раз"...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в вопросе "на сколько", а не "во сколько", так что, наверное, это разница между ними S2-S1. Добавила это код.